# how can I add a value to the list from the Dictionary<int,Object> and the list is in the Object

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Ok.. I've seen some similar discussions so I hope this is unique enough.

I would like to initialize and modify data in a List

The list is a Property of the class User, which is inside a Dictionary

http://ideone.com/0YtpnC

```
 internal class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ContactNumber> AddressBook { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, User> dic = new Dictionary<int, User>();
        dic.Add(1, new User { ID = "id1", Name = "name1" });
        dic.Add(2, new User { ID = "id2", Name = "name2" });
        dic.Add(3, new User { ID = "id3", Name = "name3", AddressBook = new List<ContactNumber>(){new ContactNumber(3432),new ContactNumber(3213)} });

        User user = dic.Where(z => z.Value.ID == "id3").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
        DisplayList(user);
        //Console.WriteLine(user.AddressBook.ToString());

        //update the list
        addOrUpdate(dic,3,user);

        //var used = new User { ID = "id1", Name = "Harry" };
        //dic[1] = used;

         user = dic.Where(z => z.Value.ID == "id3").FirstOrDefault().Value;


        Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
        DisplayList(user);


    }

    private static void DisplayList(User user)
    {
        foreach (ContactNumber number in user.AddressBook)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number.PhoneNumber);

        }
    }

    //determin list length

    public static void addOrUpdate(Dictionary<int, User> dic, int key, User user)
    {
        //sets a new user data and just replaces it in the dictionary
        //var used = new User { ID = "id1", Name = "Harry" };
        var used = new User{ ID = "id3", Name = "Henry" ,AddressBook = new List<ContactNumber>(){new ContactNumber(3111),new ContactNumber(4444)}};

        if (dic.TryGetValue(key, out user))
        {
            // yay, value exists!
            dic[key] = used;

        }
        else
        {
            // darn, lets add the value 
            dic.Add(key, used);
        }
    }



}
```

the problem is I want to get the user info and just add a contact number to the list. Currently it rewrites the entire list since I make a new version of list in the update function.

Comment: What is the purpose of providing a user to addOrUpdate? The function will always replace the key with a new User called "Henry," and the provided user is assigned but never referenced.

Comment: that entails the problem I was thinking how could I update the user, and that was a thought ( a bad/pointless one , none the less) The purpose would be to update the users information in my current problem I am having trouble figuring out how to just update the list in the User.

Comment: But if the user does not exists then you need the whole list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ideone.com/iI2Rxb
Simply: 
`dic[key].AddressBook.Add(new ContactNumber(666));`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a solution.

```
            user.AddressBook.Add(new ContactNumber() { PhoneNumber = 121212});
```

from [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

Answer (score 0):

Wont below help, just add to the list (since it is referenced, it will update whatever you have been getting from the dictionary)

user.AddressBook.Add(...new contact number);